# How to run a command from the "Start" (Search) menu in Windows 11?

Tags: start-menu, windows-11

In Windows 10 I did write this command in the search menu (Win + Q) `shutdown -h` to hibernate.
In Windows 11 the same command does not work (it does work otherwise).

It seems that the command is ran in a command line, but the arguments are not passed.

Is it a bug or missing feature, or maybe it is possible to configure somewhere?

P.S. Start menu seems to behave the same as search

Comment: The reason your shutdown command does not work is due to the fact you misspelled the command

Comment: I did misspell it here, not when I run it, I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

> How to run a command from the "Start" (Search) menu in Windows 11?

This is implemented differently in Windows 11 and not the same as Windows 10. You need to use the Run box in Windows 11 (I just use a Command Prompt).

You can type in Run,  get the Run box and enter the shutdown command that way.

This works - tested on a couple of Windows 11 machines.

Comment: Yes, this works for me as well, but I really wanted to to run it right away and I do consider this a bug since it worked before and the command is ran, just without the arguments

Comment: Yes - you need to use the Run box as trying from the Start menu no longer works in Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

In **Windows 11** I believe it needs to be either in the **Run** box or in **CMD Prompt**.

If you type **shutdown -h** in Windows 11 search bar, it recommends using Run as default.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: cmd and run box both work, this is correct. I do want it to work right from the start menu though :(

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Windows 11 will not let you use the Start Menu to run commands.